# Concatenating Tensors in C++ -

Tags: c++, tensorflow, concatenation

I've two tensors T1 of dim=1x224x224x3 and T2 of dim=1x224x224x3. I want to concatenate these 2 tensors into single tensor say T3 of dim 2x224x224x3. 
I don't know how to do in C++.

Comment: How do you store your tensor?

Comment: Varibles are Tensor T1, T2;

Comment: C++ doesn't have tensor, you either have to use a third party library or create yours

Comment: Yes, I've used Tensorflow. So after importing tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h. I'm able to use 'Tensor t1' keyword. Actually there is a documentation but it is not clear how to concat 2 tensor.

Comment: The [C++ API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/cc) guide shows how to use TensorFlow ops in C++, including an example of [`Concat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/concat). Or you can use [`Tensor::tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor#tensor_8) to get the internal [Eigen tensor](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Tensor_support) and use [`concatenate`](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/b5c7d817f0e58fdfefd54b3c79c8399519ee8f79/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorBase.h#lines-676:680).

Comment: Can you explain it with some example

Comment: @ArjunSingh I can copy and paste the example from the [C++ API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/cc) guide, but I'm not sure that would be helpful. Can you say specifically what part you are not sure about?

Comment: -Tensor t1, t2; // two tensors of 1x224x224x3. So for concatenate should I use      -list <Tensor> t12; -t12.push_back(t1); t12.push_back(t2);                                              -Tensor t3 = Concat(t21, 0);    // Concat( list, axis)                                                          So should I use something like this? '-' means new line code.

Answer (score 3):

The [C++ API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/cc) shows how to use ops in C++. For [`Concat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/concat), you would do something like this:

```
#include "tensorflow/cc/client/client_session.h"
#include "tensorflow/cc/ops/standard_ops.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h"

int main() {
  using namespace tensorflow;
  using namespace tensorflow::ops;
  Scope root = Scope::NewRootScope();
  // Tensors to concatenate
  auto t1 = Const(root, { {1.f, 2.f}, {3.f, 4.f} });
  auto t2 = Const(root, { {5.f, 6.f}, {7.f, 8.f}, {9.f, 0.f} });
  // Concatenate
  auto concatT1T2 = Concat(root.WithOpName("ConcatT1T2"), { t1, t2 }, 0);
  // Evaluate
  std::vector<Tensor> outputs;
  ClientSession session(root);
  TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({concatT1T2}, &outputs));
  // Get output tensor
  Tensor result = outputs[0];
  // Print output
  LOG(INFO) << result.matrix<float>();
  return 0;
}
```